# Can the on-board 2.4 GHz WiFi card be replaced with a dual-band on an ASUS X550 series laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, asus-laptop, dual-band, wireless-card

I have an ASUS X552L i3 with Windows 7 64 bit and I want to upgrade my 2.4 GHz WiFi card (Ralink 802.11n) with one that lets me to also connect to the 5 GHz band (so a dual band).  I know that external USB WiFi adapters exist but I am trying to see if I can replace the on-board one.

After researching for some time online, I came to the conclusion that there are no (stock) on-board WiFi cards with the 5 GHz standard for my particular laptop. All the (stock) WiFI cards have the B/G/N standard.

I pose the question: To get 5 GHz functionality on my laptop, can I find a WiFi card from one of the same OEM suppliers that also manufacture the stock 2.4 GHz cards (Realtek, Ralink, Qualcomm or maybe also from Intel (as I've seen various older threads online regarding the Intel 7260, but on other ASUS laptop models) ) by, perhaps, checking other ASUS laptops that use a dual-band card and purchase that part from somewhere online (original spare parts websites, resellers etc) and hope that it fits in my laptop and hope that the drivers from that particular ASUS model match for my ASUS model? Is this the way? **Will my BIOS even recognize it**?

On the same note, I've written an e-mail to the Technical dept. at asus.com regarding this issue and they informed me that there is no BIOS compatibility or drivers for the Intel cards and that **maybe** one of the Qualcomm Atheros devices can work, but they were unable to tell me about which part no because they do not have access to the list of compatible models (if any exists). On the Qualcomm Atheros site there are at least 20 dual-band cards ... and I still remain confused about which one can work.

If this is not the way, what is an acceptable way? Is there even a way?

Comment: Your BIOS doesn’t have to support anything. Check whether there’s a BIOS whitelist/lock for wireless hardware. If there isn’t, you can use any card.

Comment: From my understanding, there is no whitelist/lock for ASUS devices. But I may be wrong, as the official reply from asus tech. was that there's no compatibility between that laptop and a particular device from Intel. If its as you advise, and if I can find and install the drivers for a particular card, then most likely it will work. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Asus typically doesn't whitelist; they pride themselves on doing the little things that make tinkerers happy.  What really matters is whether or not your card is integrated or is just a secondary component attached to it.  It's likely the second, in which case any old card will do; it's a small card that has a couple of screws or posts in it holding the end that isn't plugged in in place.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will check in the next days what kind of device I have, once I disassemble my laptop. I consider my question answered and my problem solved. Is there anything I can do now, regarding this question?